# Elasticsearch : how to search multiple words in a copy_to field?

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I am currently learning Elasticsearch and stuck on the issue described below:

On an existing index (I don't know if it matter) I added this new mapping:

```
PUT user-index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
     "common_criteria": { -- new property which aggregates other properties by copy_to
        "type": "text"
      },
      "name": { -- already existed before this mapping
        "type": "text",
        "copy_to": "common_criteria"
      },
      "username": { -- already existed before this mapping
        "type": "text",
        "copy_to": "common_criteria"
      },
      "phone": { -- already existed before this mapping
        "type": "text",
        "copy_to": "common_criteria"
      },
      "country": { -- already existed before this mapping
        "type": "text",
        "copy_to": "common_criteria"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The goal is to search ONE or MORE values only on `common_criteria`.
Say that we have:

```
{
 "common_criteria": ["John Smith","johny","USA"]
}
```

What I would like to achieve is an exact match searching on multiple values of `common_criteria`:

1. We should have a result if we search with `John Smith` or with `USA + John Smith` or with `johny + USA` or with `USA` or with `johny` and finally with `John Smith + USA + johny` (the words order does not matter)
2. If we search with multiple words like `John Smith + Germany` or `johny + England` we should not have a result

I am using Spring Data Elastic to build my query:

```
 NativeSearchQueryBuilder nativeSearchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder();
 BoolQueryBuilder booleanQuery = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
 
 String valueToSearch = "johny"
 nativeSearchQuery.withQuery(booleanQuery.must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("common_criteria", valueToSearch)
                        .fuzziness(Fuzziness.AUTO)
                        .operator(Operator.AND)));
```

Logging the request sent to Elastic I have:

```
{
  "bool" : {
    "must" :
    {
        "match" : {
          "common_criteria" : {
            "query" : "johny",
            "operator" : "AND",
            "fuzziness" : "AUTO",
            "prefix_length" : 0,
            "max_expansions" : 50,
            "fuzzy_transpositions" : true,
            "lenient" : false,
            "zero_terms_query" : "NONE",
            "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query" : true,
            "boost" : 1.0
          }
        }
      },
    "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
    "boost" : 1.0
  }
}
```

With that request I have 0 result. I know that request is not correct because of `must.match` condition and maybe the field `common_criteria` is also not well defined.

Thanks in advance for your help and explanations.

**EDIT:** After trying `multi_match` query.

Following @rabbitbr's suggestion I tried the `multi_match` query but does not seem to work. This is the example of a request sent to Elastic (with 0 result):

```
{
  "bool" : {
    "must" : {
        "multi_match" : {
          "query" : "John Smith USA",
          "fields" : [
            "name^1.0",
            "username^1.0",
            "phone^1.0",
            "country^1.0",
          ],
          "type" : "best_fields",
          "operator" : "AND",
          "slop" : 0,
          "fuzziness" : "AUTO",
          "prefix_length" : 0,
          "max_expansions" : 50,
          "zero_terms_query" : "NONE",
          "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query" : true,
          "fuzzy_transpositions" : true,
          "boost" : 1.0
        }
    },
    "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
    "boost" : 1.0
  }
}
```

That request does not return a result.

Comment: just changing the mapping does not change existing documents and indices. You'll probably need to reindex your data to have the `common_criteria` populated

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use [Multi-match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html) before creating a field to store all the others in one place.

> The multi_match query builds on the match query to allow multi-field
> queries.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I tried it but does not seem to work, see the edit part of my post.

Comment: When you use the AND operator all terms must exist in the field, that way it won't work.
Using OR you will be successful and using boost you can make the documents you want more relevant.

Comment: It's not really accurate and returns too many results even after changing. Example almost every document containing `USA` is returned.